# using sed or awk to replace string

Tags: awk, sed, git-bash

I have one file which have many fields so I manage to pull partial data that I need using

```
variable= awk -F "," '{print $2}' filename.txt
```

and the string that I get is

```
"client":"c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee"
```

so now I want to try to change this string to

```
export client=c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee
```

when I try with

```
variable2= awk -F """ '{print $4}' $variable
```

it does not work as my plan was to pull this string first 
**62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee** then after that append **export client=** inf front of that, but I could not do that way also.

can someone help on this either awk or sed that give me that desired outcome will appreciate it.

thanks

**updates:** and here is the completed code, based on request I put masked code with sample output I'm looking for.

```
{"name":"metering","client":"c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee","client_s":"roubhaofga4mm67ncd6","audience":["metering","c68f932e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ef840fe"],"acces_allowed_types":["BEARER"],"grant_types":["CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"],"subject_type":"PUBLIC","access_t":"BEARER","id_t":"UNSIGNED_JWT","resource_":"ACCESS","resource_level":"PUBLIC","token_expiration":3600,"refresh":604800,"scopes":[{"name":"metering","description":"metering"}],"client_method":"CLPOST"}
```

what I did is

```
variable= awk -F "," '{print $2}' filename.txt
echo $variable
```

output that I'm getting is

```
"client":"c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee"
```

what I want is

```
export client=c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee
```

Comment: so you want to change the line `"client":"c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee"` to `export client=c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee` ?

Comment: Why does your output of column four contain the separator `:`?

Comment: Add output of `grep 'c62e-c5a9-4611-91c6-118b4ee' filename.txt` to your question.

Comment: Does the file contain a single line with many fields?  If field 2 contains `"quotation":"to be or not to be"`, do you want the variable `quotation` to be set and exported, or is it still `client` that needs to be set?  To what extent do you have to worry about nasty characters in the value of the string? Will the JSON-like material always have quotes around the key and the value?

Comment: Yes it always have doubles quotation, and the value is the key so I will be using that to authenticate thus important...I have also updated the first awk as I forget to change the separator ...

Comment: Something like this    variable= awk -F "," '{print $4}' filename.txt updated question also sorry guys

Comment: still not clear how you want to use the output.. would help if you gave 2-3 sample lines from original file(before awk processing) and showed expected output for that.. anyway, does this help? `cut -d, -f4 filename.txt | awk -F'"(:")?' '{print "export " $2 "=" $3}'`

Comment: @hi4ppl, please post 3 simple things in your post, 1- Sample Input_file in CODE TAGS, 2- Sample output expected in CODE TAGS with all your conditions 3rd- What you have tried in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Updated the code, thanks guys for answers

Answer (score 1):

I could see some space between equal and your command and it is not wrapped within `$` too.

```
var=$(your command)
```

Since you haven't shown us sample Input so based on what you have shown.

```
echo "$your_variable" | awk '{gsub("\042","");sub(/:/,"=");print "export",$0}'
```

Though if you could show us some sample Input and sample expected output more accurately then could have helped more on this.

Comment: Thanks, I have added sample